# JPA Query to find records who have crossed an interval over creationTime

Tags: mysql, jpa, jpql

I store creationTime inside each record.
Now I need to find out all records which have **creationTime + x seconds > current_time**.
Please help how to do this using JPQL?

---

Note that the database is MySQL and creationTime is stored in db as timestamp(3)

Comment: what format does your creationTime has in java?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("Select p from Records p " 
        + "where DATEADD(ss,numOfSeconds,creationTime) > CURDATE()");
    q.setParameter("numOfSeconds", 20);
```

bare in mind that the ss tells the function that you want to add seconds to the creationTime